# Interpretation of ROC curve curving early

Tags: r, logistic, roc, auc

I am running a binary LASSO logistic regression using glmnet. The initial data I work with is raster spatial data. When I create an ROC (AUC ~ 0.72) curve based on the test data, the resulting curve appears to curve early and has a very strange shape (shown below).

Does anyone know how I can interpret this curve and apply changes to my model to improve it?

[image: A ROC curve flattening around 0.8 FPR]

When I generate the ROC using the training data (AUC ~ 0.93), it does not appear like this.

Also, when I run the same script on coarser resolution data (30 m as opposed to the 5 m currently being used), AUC curves on training and testing data look as expected (AUC's of ~0.94 and 0.90).

Comment: It sounds like your LASSO model might be overfitting your training data. Your train/test split might also have introduced a strange bias just by chance. Try re-splitting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate an ROC curve where the TPR curved at a higher value by adjusting the weights on my rarer outcome response from 5 to 10.

It seems my finer resolution data requires higher weights for optimum results

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).